# react router on how to collapse the navbar on mobile when selecting the menu links

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

Any idea on how to collapse the navbar on mobile when selecting the menu link pages.

here is the codesandbox link, feel free to fork it.

**https://codesandbox.io/s/it6lj**

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried clicking the hamburger menu to close the menu? The code in your sandbox seems to function correctly. Perhaps I am misunderstanding what you want when you say "collapse the navbar on mobile".

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. You want that when a user selects a menu item and navigates you want the menu to close itself. This appears to be an issue related to bootstrap, retagging.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue using  Reactstrap 9.0.0-2 (based on Bootstrap 5.1.0 css library).  I'm not sure if it was a problem with earlier (more stable) releases.  Already had an idea in mind of how to get the menu to close on `NavLink` select, but wanted to see how other people solved the problem for some new ideas and experiences.

I tried the first accepted answer, adding the `data-attributes` and `data-target`
on the `NavLinks`, and pointing at a css `#id` attribute on the `NavbarToggler`.  This didn't work for me, unfortunately.

Instead, I solved the issue by setting up a click handler for the `<NavLink />` tags, independent of the handler that toggles the menu.  Unlike the other handler that opens and closes the menu, the `NavLink` handler only closes it by directly setting the menu's state object to `false`.

The logic goes: the menu has to be open in order to click on the `<NavLink />`, so this `NavLink` handler does not need to open the menu.  And once you've made your choice about where you'd like to go, and have clicked on a `Navlink` tag, you'd probably like the menu to close and get out of your way, rather than having to close it yourself manually.

- Simplified example:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Collapse, Nav, NavBar, NarbarBrand, NavbarToggler, NavItem } from 'reactstrap';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

const Header = (props) => {
    const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false);  // initially closed

    const toggleMenu = () => {     // this handler is "regular"
        setMenuOpen(!menuOpen);    // open and close...
    };

    const closeMenu = () => {      // ... and this one only
        setMenuOpen(false);    // closes it ...
    };

return (
  <NavBar expand="md">
    <Collapse isOpen={menuOpen} navbar>
      <Nav navbar>
        <NavLink
          to="/blog/:article"
          className="navlink text-light shadow-lg"
          onClick={closeMenu}
         >
          {blogArticle.title}
          </NavLink>
                     // . . . and so on . . .
```

Sometimes the simplest solutions are also the best...

Comment: I will try this, btw Im using bootstrap 4.6 and react 17.0.2.

Comment: If you're toggling (opening and closing) the menu with a click handler, it's wired up to the state (`menuOpen`), which is controlling the right thing (shown here: `<Collapse isOpen={menuOpen} />`) and the link `onClick` closer is wired up to the same thing as the toggler (but just closing it), in theory it should work regardless what library you're using.

Comment: Can you make a sandbox or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Add `data-toggle="collapse"` and `data-target="#navbarCollapse"` to each `NavLink` to also toggle closed the menu.

```
<ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
  <li className="nav-item">
    <NavLink
      data-toggle="collapse"
      data-target="#navbarCollapse"
      className="nav-link"
      activeClassName="active"
      to="/"
      exact
    >
      Home
    </NavLink>
  </li>
  <li className="nav-item">
    <NavLink
      data-toggle="collapse"
      data-target="#navbarCollapse"
      className="nav-link"
      activeClassName="active"
      to="/about"
    >
      About
    </NavLink>
  </li>
```

[image: Edit epic-microservice-hvmlf]

Answer (score 1):

you can manage the menu visibility using a state:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const Navbar = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const handleNavClick = () => {
    setShow(false);
  };
  return (
    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a className="navbar-brand" href="/">
        Fixed navbar
      </a>
      <button
        className="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        onClick={() => setShow(!show)}
      >
        <span className="navbar-toggler-icon" />
      </button>
      <div
        className={`collapse navbar-collapse  ${show ? "show" : ""}`}
        id="navbarCollapse"
      >
        <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li className="nav-item">
            <NavLink
              onClick={handleNavClick}
              className="nav-link"
              activeClassName="active"
              to="/"
              exact
            >
              Home
            </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <NavLink
              onClick={handleNavClick}
              className="nav-link"
              activeClassName="active"
              to="/about"
            >
              About
            </NavLink>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `useRef` hook for this and handle the class attribute of the div.

```
  const collapseRef = useRef(null);

  const hideBars = () => {
    collapseRef.current.setAttribute("class", "navbar-collapse collapse");
  };

  <div
    className="collapse navbar-collapse"
    id="navbarCollapse"
    ref={collapseRef}
  >
```

and then in your NavLink

```
        <NavLink
          className="nav-link"
          activeClassName="active"
          to="/about"
          onClick={hideBars}
        >
          About
        </NavLink>
```

Check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-currying-6w8yz) sandbox

Answer (score 0):

if some still have this issue in bootsrap 5 just add these props to the li tag like this:

```
 <li className="nav-item" data-bs-toggle='collapse' data-bs-target='.navbar-collapse.show'>
      <Link className="nav-link" to="/">
        <img src={homepage_icon} className='nav-item-icon' />
        <h6>Page d'accueil</h6>
      </Link>
```

and you end up by collapsing navbar